# Is it correct to use "anniversary" to commemorate a sad event or is it better to use "memorial"

Tags: vocabulary

Is it correct to use "anniversary" to commemorate a sad event or is it better to use "memorial". Or is there, in fact, a better term?

For instance, "observing the 20th anniversary of the Rwanda genocide" vs "observing the 20 year memorial of the Rwanda genocide?

Comment: And do you want to "commemorate" the anniversary of a sad event or "observe" it?

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Google Books ["anniversary of his death"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22anniversary+of+his+death%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) 1,670,000 results.

Comment: @Peter: Here in the UK we ["commemorate the dead"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commemorate+the+dead%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Particularly on Remembrance Day (Armistice Day, Veterans Day), and most particularly at 11 o'clock.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To expand my comment, *"observe"* sounds to me like a verb with the wrong connotations, since I associate it with religious practices, although we could *"observe"* a minute of silence in honor of the victims. We would use *"commmemorate"* in the US as well.

Comment: @Peter: I don't particularly associate "observe" with religious ceremonies (maybe it's a bit "precious", but I certainly *hear* [observe the common decencies](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22observe+the+common+decencies%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), even though I probably wouldn't use it myself). To me the distinction is that we "observe" something that we do in the present. We "commemorate" something that happened (or someone that died) in the past.

Answer (score 4):

I see the difficulty with using 'anniversary', but I believe it to be the correct word to use. The problem is that 'memorial' does not mean the same thing.

Whilst 'anniversary' literally relates to a year date, a 'memorial' is a specific structure, service or other commemoration of an event, which may or may not be related to a one-year time period. In your example you are trying to get across the idea of the annual date, and 'memorial' does not do that.

Unfortunately the word 'anniversary' usually relates to a celebration of some kind e.g. wedding anniversary. It is however used to describe, for example, events in war such as the 70th anniversary of the Normandy landings, which will be on 6th June this year.

But because it is often associated with happiness, if I were using it for something as dreadful as the Rwanda genocide, I think I would qualify it in some way. You could say, for example, 'by observing the tragic anniversary of the Rwanda genocide', or ' observing the anniversary of the appalling genocide in Rwanda'.

Comment: That's a great answer. "Anniversary" is neutral, so it is whether you use "celebrate", "commemorate", etc that defines it. You would not, of course, "celebrate" the anniversary of the Rwandan genocide, but you could "honour" or "commemorate" it.

Comment: @nxx Yes, 'honour', 'commemorate', 'observe' all work here.

Comment: There are millions of Google results when you search for ["9/11 anniversary"](https://www.google.com/search?q=anniversary+of+9%2F11&oq=anniversary+of+9%2F11&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4023j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=%229%2F11+anniversary%22) and many of those are not qualified by an adjective like *tragic* or *appalling*, maybe because we in the U.S. don't yet need to be reminded of how awful that day was.

Comment: @JLG It is the same with some of the terrorist atrocities in Northern Ireland. We speak of 'the anniversary of the Omagh bombings'. Also the anniversary of the sinking of the Titanic. But there just seems to be something about the Rwanda genocide that I for one could not mention it without some reference to tragedy.